# How to load a view dynamically in a modal according to the clicked link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog

I would like to load the view inside a modal to do the operations, however I thought of dynamically loading the views according to the clicked link, having only one modal instead of three, how would I do that? Or better create the same modal ones, one for each operation?

ps: The question is not how to open a modal but how to load the view dynamically within the modal, changing the name of the same confirm the click on the link (deposit, draw, extract), reusing a single modal.

```
<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($info as $info) {
        echo "<li>Titular: {$info->titular} </li> "
            . "<li>Agência: {$info->agencia} </li>"
            . "<li> Conta: {$info->conta} </li> "
            . "<li>Saldo: R$" . number_format($info->saldo, 2, ',', '.') . "</li>";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
<a class="operacao" id="deposito" href="">Deposito</a>
<a class="operacao" id ="saque" href="">Saque</a>
<a class="operacao" id="extrato" href="">Extrato</a>

<div class="modal">
    <?php $this->loadView('deposito', $this->getData()); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery to load the data on click--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#deposito').click(function(){
             $('#modal1 .modal-body').html(htmldata);
             $('#modal1').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'});
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually make it easy on myself and create three different divs inside my modal each with different ids which I show and hide according to the link clicked.

So for example, my modal would look like this,

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class='views' id='view_1'>
  ....
  </div>
  <div class='views' id='view_2'>
  ....
  </div>
  <div class='views' id='view_3'>
  ....
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I create an onclick handler to hide show each div in the modal after getting the data, like so for example

```
$('view-1-link').click(function(){
   // get your data with ajax
   $('.views').hide(); // hide all views
   $('#view_1').html(data).show();
})
```

Then do the same for each view link.

Hope this helps!